# JSON request doesn't always return same response type (object & array)

Tags: json, swift, xcode

TL;DR: One JSON request sometimes returns an object and sometimes returns an array of objects for a key and I don't know how to parse that correctly with Swift 4.

Preface: I'm making a bus service app using the [NextBus API](https://www.nextbus.com/xmlFeedDocs/NextBusXMLFeed.pdf) to provide bus schedule updates and predictions for buses in the Chapel Hill area. However, I'm running into a problem when fetching prediction information for a bus stop (*Prediction request info on pp 13-15 of NextBus API PDF*).

The Problem:

A request for a stop prediction returns two keys: "predictions" and "copyright". While the "copyright" key always returns a string for a prediction request, the "predictions" key will sometimes return an object and sometimes return an array depending on whether there are two buses on the route or not.

Here's the problem visualized with Postman:

*Predictions returns an array:*

```
{
"predictions": [
    {
        "agencyTitle": "Chapel Hill Transit",
        "routeTag": "N",
        "routeTitle": "N",
        "stopTitle": "Estes Park Apts - Departure",
        "stopTag": "estepark",
        "dirTitleBecauseNoPredictions": "To Family Practice Building"
    },
    {
        "agencyTitle": "Chapel Hill Transit",
        "routeTag": "N",
        "routeTitle": "N",
        "stopTitle": "Estes Park Apts - Arrival",
        "stopTag": "estepark_a",
        "dirTitleBecauseNoPredictions": "To Family Practice Building"
    }
],
"copyright": "All data copyright Chapel Hill Transit 2018." 
}
```

*Predictions returns an object:*

```
{
"predictions": {
    "agencyTitle": "Chapel Hill Transit",
    "routeTag": "A",
    "routeTitle": "A",
    "stopTitle": "Martin Luther King Jr Blvd  at Timber Hollow",
    "stopTag": "airptimb_s",
    "dirTitleBecauseNoPredictions": "To Northside"
},
"copyright": "All data copyright Chapel Hill Transit 2018."
}
```

I'm making this application in Xcode 9.4.1 using Swift 4. Here's my current code to handle the request:

```
func fetchStopPrediction(stopId: String, routeTag: String, completion: @escaping (Predictions) -> Void) {
    let routeInfo = "\(stopId)&routeTag=\(routeTag)"
    let urlString = baseUrl + routeInfo
    print(urlString)

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let jsonResponse = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(jsonResponse)")
        }

        if let data = response.data {
            do {
                let predictions = try self.decoder.decode(Predictions.self, from: data)
                completion(predictions)
            } catch let error {
                print("Error", error)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Predictions: Codable {
    let predictions: [Prediction?]
    let copyright: String?
}
```

Comment: **Ouch.** The pain of integrating with a poorly-designed API. `predictions` should **always** be an array, even if it only has one entry. Maybe worth a note to Chapel Hill about it. Wish I could help with the Swift (not my area of expertise). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info, going to try to implement that now. How silly is it to give a key a plural name and then return a single object?

Comment: Well, that would be okay (naming is one of the two hard problems in computer science, the others are cache invalidation and dealing with off-by-one errors). But it should be consistent. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write a custom initializer. First decode a dictionary, if it fails decode an array

```
struct Predictions : Decodable {
    let predictions: [Prediction]
    let copyright: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case predictions, copyright }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        copyright = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .copyright)
        do {
            let prediction = try container.decode(Prediction.self, forKey: .predictions)
            predictions = [prediction]
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            predictions = try container.decode([Prediction].self, forKey: .predictions)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this require any changes to my `fetchStopPrediction` method?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: jrend, you should also give credit to vadian. You just selected this as the correct answer but no credit given :)

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to Stack Overflow and the etiquette that surrounds it. By giving credit, do you mean edit my question and say vadian's answer solved my issue? If so, I just did that. Hope that suffices!